# Adding a parameter to the URL in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to have a parameter as part of my ASP MVC URL **before** Controller and Action:

http://www.mydomain.com/**company1**/Home

or

http://www.mydomain.com/**company1**/Clients/Detail/1

(Ideally I would like to have this as a sub-domain like this: http://**company1**.mydomain.com/Clients/Detail/1 so any answers solving this one is also appreciated)

I call this parameter Account. I tried adding something like this to the routing map:
"{account}/{controller}/{action}/{id}" but it gives me a 404 error when trying something like http://www.mydomain.com/company1/Home

Here is the RegisterRoutes in Global.asax:

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
           routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("TestRoute", "{account}/{controller}/{action}/{id}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
}
```

Is there anything special I have to do when organising my Views folder or Controller actions?

Comment: Can you show your exact routing set up from global.asax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error sounds like you are not giving a default for action in your route defaults.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, too, but with out the exact routes it's hard to tell.

Comment: You are absolutely right guys! Adding defaults fixed the issue. But how can I get hold of the account value in my controller actions?

Comment: Add a string parameter to your action method with the same name and it should get filled in by MVC.